# Highcharts graph not showing

Tags: highcharts

On this webpage, https://betterbuildingssolutioncenter.energy.gov/energy-data/Cascap%20Inc. , the graph next to the "Whole building vs. Owner-paid Performance" section is not showing. What part of the code needs to be fixed in order for this graph to show? The "RenderTo: energy-intensity" part is correct.

```js
// color declarations
var colorGreen = '#0b6a39',
    colorBlue = '#0c4489',
    colorGray = '#595959',
    font = 'avenir';

// graph data variables
// Portfolio Energy Performance
var /* title */             energyPerformanceTitle = 'EUI and % Improvement vs. Baseline',
        /* columns */           energyPerformanceCategories = ['2013 Baseline', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
        /* Y max */             energyPerformanceYMax = 100,
        /* X title */           energyPerformanceXaxis = [''],
        /* Y title */           energyPerformanceYaxis = ['Source EUI (kBtu/sq. ft.)'],
        /* column colors */     energyPerformanceColumns = [colorBlue, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen],
        /* column data */       energyPerformanceData = [92, 88, 86, 84, 82, 84, 79, 79],
        /* goal data */         energyPerformanceGoalData = 74,
    energyPerformanceInterval = 25;

// Energy Performance by Facility
var /* title */         energyFacilityTitle = 'Number of Properties by Cumulative % Improvement',
        /* columns */           energyFacilityCategories = ['&lt;=0%', '0-2%', '2-6%', '6-10%', '10-15%', '>15%'],
        /* X title */           energyFacilityXaxis = ['Cumulative % Improvement Category'],
        /* Y title */           energyFacilityYaxis = ['Number of Properties'],
        /* Y interval */        energyFacilityYinterval = 1,
        /* column colors */     energyFacilityColumns = [colorBlue, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen],
        /* column data */       energyFacilityData = [5, 2, 0, 2, 2, 9];

// Identifying Opportunities for Improvement
var /* title */         improvementOpportunityTitle = '% Improvement vs. Baseline EUI',
        /* columns */           improvementOpportunityCategories = ['0', '50', '100', '150', '200', '250'],
        /* X min */         improvementOpportunityXMin = 0,
        /* X max */         improvementOpportunityXMax = 150,
        /* Y min */         improvementOpportunityYMin = -30,
        /* Y max */         improvementOpportunityYMax = 40,
        /* Y interval */        improvementOpportunityYinterval = 10,
        /* X interval */        improvementOpportunityXinterval = 50,
        /* X title */           improvementOpportunityXaxis = ['Baseline Source EUI (kBtu/sq.ft.)'],
        /* Y title */           improvementOpportunityYaxis = ['% Improvement'],
        /* scatter data */      improvementOpportunityData = [[59, -3], [73, 17], [75, 37], [109, 2], [88, -30], [108, -20], [124, -2], [107, -4], [91, 13], [99, 27], [135, 20], [108, 12], [110, 24], [101, 24], [89, 0], [116, 21], [96, 17], [107, 9], [110, 8], [6, 22]],
        /* trendline data */    improvementOpportunityTrendLine = [[6, 16], [135, 7]];

// Energy Intensity
var /* title */         energyEnergyTitle = 'EUI and % Improvement vs. Baseline',
        /* columns */           energyEnergyCategories = ['2013 Baseline', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
        /* Y title */           energyEnergyYaxis = ['Source EUI (kBtu/sq. ft.)'],
        /* column colors */     energyEnergyColumns = [colorBlue, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen],
        /* column data */       energyEnergyData = [[11, -2], [278, 18]],
    energyEnergyGoalData = 74,
    energyEnergyMax = 100,
    energyEnergyInterval = 20,
    energyEnergyA = [92, 88, 86, 84, 82, 84, 79, 79],
    energyEnergyB = [96, 92, 89, 87, 85, 87, 82, 82],
    energyEnergyC = [6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4];

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = energyPerformanceCategories;
        options.colors = energyPerformanceColumns,
            options.series = [{
                type: 'column',
                name: energyPerformanceYaxis,
                data: energyPerformanceData,
                color: colorGreen,
                colorByPoint: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'energy-performance',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: energyPerformanceTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                column: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyPerformanceXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyPerformanceYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickInterval: energyPerformanceInterval,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                max: energyPerformanceYMax,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 2,
                    value: energyPerformanceGoalData,
                    zIndex: 5,
                    label: {
                        text: 'GOAL',
                        align: 'right',
                        x: 22,
                        y: -5,
                        style: {
                            color: colorGray,
                            fontFamily: font,
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var raw = ((this.y / energyPerformanceData[0])) * 100,
                        percentage = Math.round(100 - (raw * 100) / 100);
                    if (this.y === energyPerformanceData[0] && this.key === '2013 Baseline')
                        return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + this.y;
                    else
                        return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + this.y + '<br/>' + percentage + '% improvement from baseline';

                }
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = energyFacilityCategories;
        options.colors = energyFacilityColumns,
            options.series = [{
                type: 'column',
                name: energyFacilityYaxis,
                data: energyFacilityData,
                color: colorGreen,
                colorByPoint: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'facility-performance',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: energyFacilityTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                column: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyFacilityXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    y: 30,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyFacilityYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickInterval: energyFacilityYinterval,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorTickColor: colorGray,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + this.y;
                }
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = improvementOpportunityCategories;
        options.series = [{
            name: improvementOpportunityYaxis,
            data: improvementOpportunityData,
            color: colorBlue
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Trendline',
            data: improvementOpportunityTrendLine,
            color: colorGray,
            width: 1,
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'improvement-opportunities',
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: improvementOpportunityTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 3,
                        symbol: 'diamond',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: improvementOpportunityXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                min: improvementOpportunityXMin,
                max: improvementOpportunityXMax,
                tickInterval: improvementOpportunityXinterval,
                minTickInterval: 25,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: improvementOpportunityYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                min: improvementOpportunityYMin,
                max: improvementOpportunityYMax,
                tickInterval: improvementOpportunityYinterval,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 1,
                    value: 0
                }, {
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 1,
                    value: 0,
                    zIndex: 5
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<strong>' + this.series.name + ':</strong> ' + this.y;
                }
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = energyEnergyCategories;
        options.colors = energyEnergyColumns,
            options.series = [{
                name: 'Portfolio',
                type: 'column',
                data: energyEnergyA,
                color: colorGreen,
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ''
                }

            }, {
                name: 'Whole Building',
                type: 'column',
                data: energyEnergyB,
                color: colorBlue,
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ''
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Owner-Paid Receipts',
                type: 'column',
                //yAxis: 1,
                data: energyEnergyC,
                color: colorBlueLight,
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ''
                }
            }];


        [{
            type: 'column',
            name: energyEnergyYaxis,
            data: energyEnergyData,
            color: colorGreen,
            colorByPoint: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'energy-intensity',
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: energyEnergyTitle
            },

            xAxis: [{
                tickLength: 0,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                categories: energyEnergyCategories
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: energyEnergyYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray
                    }
                },
                tickLength: 6,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 2,
                    value: energyEnergyGoalData,
                    zIndex: 5,
                    label: {
                        text: 'GOAL',
                        align: 'right',
                        x: 22,
                        y: -5,
                        style: {
                            color: colorGray,
                            fontFamily: font,
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                tickInterval: energyEnergyInterval,
                max: energyEnergyMax
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray
                    }
                },

                opposite: true


            }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {

                itemDistance: 50
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    shadow: false
                }
            },
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});
```

Comment: looking in the console - colorBlueLight isn't defined on line 2066

Comment: That was it, thank you! @Barbara Laird